# Use Type Parameter in View Definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have several maintenance tables in a db and want to set up reusable views for all of them.  I'd like to do something like the snippet below but can't figure out how to pass the type in from Razor/HTML.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index<T>() where T : class 
{
    return View(await db.Set<T>().ToListAsync());
}
```

Below are two attempts.

First, I tried passing the type name in as a string then getting the type.  But Entity Framework didn't like this (`db` is an instance of a class inheriting from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Action", "Controller", new { type = "MyType" }, null)


public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string type)
{
    return View(await db.Set(Type.GetType(type)).ToListAsync());
}
```

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyType]'.

Second, I tried passing the type.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Action", "Controller", new { type = typeof(MyType) }, null)


public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Type type)
{
    return View(await db.Set(type).ToListAsync());
}
```

This didn't work at all.  The parameter `type` was null.

Any thoughts on a new approach or how to get one of the above to work?

Comment: `await db.Set(Type.GetType(type)).ToListAsync()` What does Set async method return? Could also you show ViewModel class?

Comment: That line throws the error I quoted above "The model item passed into the dictionary...".  The relevant code from the ViewModel are pasted right below the HTML in each scenario - the ViewModel only has an `Index` method